# itemize in hbox – Perhaps a missing \item

Tags: itemize

When compiling the following code with pdflatex

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\hbox{\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem Ipsum
\end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                 
l.5 \item L
           orem Ipsum
```

What is the reason for this?
Can this be solved such that it sets in the expected manner?
I already figured out that wrapping a `minipage` around the `itemize` inside the `hbox` works but it depends on being able to determine the correct width of the `minipage` – which would be `\textwidth` in the MWE but not in my actual usecase.

Comment: You can't use `itemize` in a `\hbox`, `itemize` needs to be able to enter vertical mode, which it can't in a horizontal box, you have to use it in a `minipage` or `\parbox`. But you could fake an `itemize` like appearance with a `tabular` rather easily.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your aim is, but you can perhaps use `varwidth`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\fbox{% just to show that this grows up to what's needed
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
Some text
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem Ipsum
\item Some longer lorem
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}%<--- just because we're in an \fbox
}

\end{document}
```

The `\fbox` around the `varwidth` is just to show the boundaries of the built box; `varwidth` builds a minipage.

[image]